# Radio button does not work in foreach loop MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core-rc2

Can someone explain me why radio buttons does not work in my View? Here is the code snippet

```
        @foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(CertificateAuthorityChoiceTypes)))
        {
            <tr id="enum-tr" data-toggle="collapse">
                <td>
                    <label id="enum-val" class="c-input c-radio">
                        <input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio">
                        <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                        @item
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
         }
```

As you can see everything is in table. When I paste checkbox code outside of foreach loop checkbox works, but inside foreach I just does not work.. Please give me some suggestions where the bug can be.

Comment: You not give each radio button a `value` attribute (and your generating invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes)

Answer (score 0):

id of the radios are same.Radio's ids must be different.

Comment: So I assigned id of value @item and it still does not work.

Comment: Change the id like this <input id="@item" name="radio" type="radio">

Comment: Yes I did that and still doesn't work, but if I do <input id="@item" name="radio" type="radio" checked >  then the last item is checked, but others aren't

Comment: You can select only one radio from the radio group with same name.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
@foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Stream)))
{
<tr id="@("enum-tr"+Enum.GetNames(typeof(Stream)).ToList().IndexOf(item))" data-toggle="collapse">
    <td>
        <label id="@("enum-val"+Enum.GetNames(typeof(Stream)).ToList().IndexOf(item))" class="c-input c-radio">
            <input id="@("radio"+Enum.GetNames(typeof(Stream)).ToList().IndexOf(item))" name="radio" type="radio">
            <span class="c-indicator"></span>
            @item
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Still nothing happened ;/

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the bug.. The problem was in

```
 <tr id="enum-tr" data-toggle="collapse">
```

when I removed `data-toggle="collapse"` checkboxes started to work just fine